# How to convert a nested array in javascript to json structure

Tags: javascript, json

In the following code i am trying to populate the javascript class,such that i get an object which i can stringify to json string.

```
       function classValue(valuearrs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < valuearrs.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < valuearrs[i].length; j++) {

                this.id = valuearrs[i][j];
                this.name = valuearrs[i][j];
                this.somekey = valuearrs[i][j];
            }
        }
  }


   function CreatenestedarrObj( valuearr) {

        this.Arrayparameters = [new classValue (valuearr)];
    }

   function ArrayMethodCall() {

       var valuearr = new Array();
       valuearr[0] = "myval1";
       valuearr[1] = "myval2";
       valuearr[2] = "myval3";
       var valuearr1 = new Array();
       valuearr1[0] = "myval11";
       valuearr1[1] = "myval12";
       valuearr1[2] = "myval13";
       nestedarr = new Array();
       nestedarr[0] = valuearr;
       nestedarr[1] = valuearr1;

       var x = new CreatenestedarrObj( nestedarr);
       var strobject = JSON.stringify(x);
       alert(strobject);
   }

   </script>
  </head> <body> MethodCall: <input type="button" value="Call Method" onclick=" ArrayMethodCall ()" />
```

After Stringifying the value expected is {ArrayParameters:[{myval1,myval2,myval3},{myval1,myval12,myval13}]}.The  thing i can think i am missing is creating new object each time in the loop but how ? or i might be totally wrong.Any help will be  much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
function classValue(valuearrs) {
        var arr=[]
          for (var i = 0; i < valuearrs.length; i++) {
              arr[i]={};
            for (j = 0; j < valuearrs[i].length; j++) {

                arr[i].id = valuearrs[i][j];
                arr[i].name = valuearrs[i][j];
                arr[i].somekey = valuearrs[i][j];
            }
        }
          return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
    function classValue(valuearrs) {
        var arr = []
        for (var i = 0; i < valuearrs.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < valuearrs[i].length; j++) {
                var temp = new Object();
                temp.id = valuearrs[i][j];
                temp.name = valuearrs[i][j];
                temp.somekey = valuearrs[i][j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need to split the `nestedarr` to `id`,`name` and `somekey`
but if you don't need to, just return the `valuearrs` and you will be fine:

```
function classValue(valuearrs) {
    return valuearrs;
  }


   function CreatenestedarrObj( valuearr) {

        this.Arrayparameters = [new classValue (valuearr)];
    }

   function ArrayMethodCall() {

       var valuearr = new Array();
       valuearr[0] = "myval1";
       valuearr[1] = "myval2";
       valuearr[2] = "myval3";
       var valuearr1 = new Array();
       valuearr1[0] = "myval11";
       valuearr1[1] = "myval12";
       valuearr1[2] = "myval13";
       nestedarr = new Array();
       nestedarr[0] = valuearr;
       nestedarr[1] = valuearr1;

       var x = new CreatenestedarrObj( nestedarr);
       var strobject = JSON.stringify(x);
       console.info(strobject);
   }
```

the output is

```
{"Arrayparameters":[[["myval1","myval2","myval3"],["myval11","myval12","myval13"]]]}
```

or far better if you don't want it as  `Arrayparameters`, you can use following code

```
var strobject = JSON.stringify(nestedarr);
```

and the output will be like this :

```
[["myval1","myval2","myval3"],["myval11","myval12","myval13"]]
```

Comment: Got the answer down.Syntactically In Json String array objects elements will be in {} .Thanks for replying.